# NextJS bug: Component props are undefined when building the project (everything works fine on dev mode)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I have this component that works totally fine on dev mode but when building it tells me that the `open` prop is `undefined` even though it works fine and when I `console.log` it on localhost I get the correct result.

```
const FAQ = ({ faq, index, toggleFAQ }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={`${Styles.faq} ${faq.open ? Styles.open : ""}`}
      key={index}
      onClick={() => toggleFAQ(index)}>
      <div className={Styles.question}>
        <div className='flex justify-between'>
          <div style={{ width: "90%" }}>
            <span>{faq.question}</span>
          </div>
          <div className='m-auto ml-24'>
            {faq.open ? (
              <img src='faq1.svg' alt='' srcSet='' />
            ) : (
              <img src='faq2.svg' alt='' srcSet='' />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>{" "}
      <div className={Styles.answer}>
        <span>{faq.answer}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Where I'm passing the prop:

```
const FAQpage = () => {
  const [faqs, setfaqs] = useState([
    {
      question: "1",answer:"2",open: true,
    },
    {
      question: "1",answer:"2",open: false,
    },
    {
      question:"1",answer:"2",open: false,
    },
    {
      question:"1",answer:"2",open: false,
    },
    {
      question:"1",answer:"2",open: false,
    },
    {
      question:"1",answer:"2",open: false,
    },
    {
      question:"1",answer:"2",open: false,
    },
  ]);

  const toggleFAQ = (index) => {
    setfaqs(
      faqs.map((faq, i) => {
        if (i === index) {
          faq.open = !faq.open;
        } else {
          faq.open = false;
        }

        return faq;
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className={Styles.title}>FAQ</h1>
      <div className={Styles.faqs}>
        {faqs &&
          faqs.map((faq, i) => (
            <FAQ faq={faq} key={i} index={i} toggleFAQ={toggleFAQ} />
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Error running `next build`:

```
info - Creating an optimized production build info - Compiled successfully 
info - Collecting page data [= ] info - Generating static pages (0/51) 
Error occurred prerendering page "/components/FAQ". Read more: err.sh/next.js/prerender-error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
```

I can't tell if this is a bug from NextJS side or what, I have been trying to rebuild the project for a while and this same error keeps popping. I have this same error on another component (basically the same concept where I'm passing props this same way). Any help would be really appreciated, thanks

Comment: Do you get the error when running `next build`? Could you add the specific error you're getting?

Comment: I get it when running npm run build which is next build

Comment: info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data  
[=   ] info  - Generating static pages (0/51)
Error occurred prerendering page "/components/FAQ". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Answer (score 6):

The build fails because you have components under the `pages/` folder:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/components/FAQ".
```

Next.js uses this folder structure for routing, so you can only have page components in it. You'll need to move your components out of `pages/` to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks man, components definitely needs to be out of pages

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell just by the code you posted here, but if you are trying to use "getStaticPaths" with "fallback: true", you have to add a condition to check if isFallback, like this:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const App = () => {
  const router = useRouter()

  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <FallbackComponent />
  } else {
    return <MyApp />
  }
}
```

If you don't want to render a fallback component you can use fallback: "blocking" and it will SSR your page if it is not available. Beware that if your user (or crawler) is accessing a page for the first time it can take a while until the page is completely rendered (and during this time the page will be blank with no interaction).